# Unfortunately, MiAplicacion has stopped android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #

Tags: android

Intento emular una aplicación, la aplicación se ejecuta correctamente, pero al clickear para hacer una acción ya me aparece el error de:

> Unfortunately, NombreApp has stopped

Y la aplicación se cierra.

Este es mi MainActivity

```
package com.example.rodry.contador;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    display = 0;

}

public void incrementar(View vista){
    display++;
    mostrarResultado();
}

public void decrementar(View vista){
    display--;
    mostrarResultado();
}

public void resetear(View vista){
    display = 0;
    mostrarResultado();
}

public void mostrarResultado(){
    TextView miContador = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contador);
    miContador.setText(display);
    }
}
```

Y este es el código de content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.rodry.contador.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<Button
    android:text="+2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/sum2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:text="+1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sum2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sum2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sum2"
    android:id="@+id/sum1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:onClick="incrementar"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:text="+5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sum2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sum2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sum2"
    android:id="@+id/sum5"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contador"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:text="Reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sum2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="resetear"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Pongo el código de la Excepción para ver si vosotros sabéis como solucionarlo

> 09-26 07:29:11.669 5727-5727/com.example.rodry.contador
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.rodry.contador, PID: 5727
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x1
>                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.rodry.contador.MainActivity.mostrarResultado(MainActivity.java:38)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.rodry.contador.MainActivity.incrementar(MainActivity.java:23)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error. **InvocationTargetException** :

> java.lang.reflect.**InvocationTargetException** at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick

Regularmente es provocado por un error en el metodo que manda llamar la vista. En este caso este es el problema:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x1 at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)

Revisando el código, tanto `incrementar()` como `resetear()`, mandan llamar el método:

```
public void mostrarResultado(){
    TextView miContador = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contador);
    miContador.setText(display);
    }
```

El cual tiene el problema ya que por el mensaje de error trata de cargar un recurso, ya que el método `setText(int resID)` recibe un id tipo int de un recurso, si recibe un valor de 1 (#0x1) , trata de buscar este id que en realidad no existe.

Asegura que el texto sea siempre un String mediante este cambio:

```
miContador.setText(String.valueOf(display));
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Rodrypaladin Si la respuesta de Elenasys te ayudo marcala como respuesta correcta pulsando el boton en forma de V del lado izquierdo, asi futuros usuarios sabran que esta respuesta es util y tu ganaras reputación en el sitio :)

Comment: Vale, gracias, no sabía que se tenía que realizar esa acción

Comment: @Rodrypaladin que bien solucionaste tu problema, saludos!

Comment: @Rodrypaladin es una forma en que el sitio le da mejor visibilidad a las respuestas y usuarios futuros con el mismo problema encuentran mas facil la solucion correcta que en foros tradicionales :)