# Error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8 en Android

Tags: java, android

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8

Log de error:

```
09-29 19:23:27.975 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: app.descubrirosona.lite, PID: 27051
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8
      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4138)
      at app.descubrirosona.lite.adapters.RouteAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RouteAdapter.java:92)
      at app.descubrirosona.lite.adapters.RouteAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RouteAdapter.java:26)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
```

la linea del código RouteAdapter.java:92

```
holder.tvDistance.setText(item.getDistance());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8

Puede ser que el recurso no se encuentre ya que el archivo `R.java` (Archivo auto generable) no se genero correctamente; aunque en últimas versiones de Android Studio no he visto suceda.

Actualmente es más común como sucede en este caso:
[Unfortunately, MiAplicacion has stopped](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25044/unfortunately-miaplicacion-has-stopped/25052#25052)

El método usado `setText()` espera recibir un valor de tipo `String` pero por alguna razón recibio un `int` y trata de interpretar el valor como un id de recurso:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(123);
```

Una solución rápida es usando `String.valueOf()` :

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(123));
```

(La razón de usar `String.valueOf()` es que con cualquier valor no produciría error, incluso si la **variable** a desplegar mediante `setText()` es de valor `NULL`)

Esto aplica también para el método `setHint()`.

Answer (score 2):

El error indica que se esperaba un `String` normalmente lo muestra cuando se obtiene de datos numéricos.

Para solucionar se debe realizar un `cast`, por ejemplo si es a partir de un entero:

```
Integer.toString(int);
```

Comment: Amigo @Webserveis, escorrecto lo que comentas, aunque yo usaría String,valueOf() , la razón es que pudiera venir un valor no numérico y provocaría otro problema, incluso si se recibiera un valor NULL no se produciría un error =) (Aclaro se puede validar pero empezaríamos a agregar más lineas de código tal vez innnecesarias).