# Utilizar valores de los strings.xml

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código en el string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
         <string name="hint_input_user_es">EMAIL:</string>
    </resources>
```

Y lo que quiero es obtener "CORREO ELECTRÓNICO" y mostrarlo en un textView como Hint. Lo he probado de varias formas y con todas me da el mismo error.

```
TextView login_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_email);

1. login_email.setHint(getText(R.string.hint_input_user_es));
2. login_email.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_input_user_es));
3. login_email.setHint(getString(R.string.hint_input_user_es));
```

Y en todos lo casos me da este error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f05002b
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: El nombre de tu string termina en **es** y lo estás llamando con **en**

Comment: Disculpa ya edite la pregunta, fui yo que me confundí escribiendo la pregunta

Comment: en algún lugar de tu código establecias un valor entero para el método setHint() o setText() , esa es la razón para el error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID.

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25529/error-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0xbb8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logre probar este código y funciono correctamente

```
TextView hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
String hint2 = getResources().getString(R.string.hint2);
hint.setHint(hint2);

<resources>
    <string name="hint2">HINT2</string>
</resources>
```

Pero me parece que el TextView aun que tenga un campo Hint, no aplica para que esa información se despliegue en pantalla.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:text="TextView"/>
```

¿Tal vez puede que pensaras mas en un EditText? Ya que en el EditText cuando no hay nada escrito, muestra el Hint

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/hint"/>
```

Nota: probé el mismo código con un EditText y también funciona

Comment: "en lugar de establecer el valor del Hint desde el código, lo hagas desde el XML de tu vista" , **no se debe recomendar esto ya que las dos opciones deben funcionar sin problema**.

Answer (score -2):

El valor del "hint" o texto, se puede establecer **sin problema** prográmaticamente  :

```
myEditText.setHint("Escribe algo!");
```

o directamente a la vista.

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Escribe algo!"/>
```

Con respecto al error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   `#0x7f05002b`

en algún punto de tu código estas asignando ya sea al método setHint() o setText() un valor entero, tu mismo puedes realizar la prueba para ver lo que comento.

Agrego una respuesta similar:

[Error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8 en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25529/error-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0xbb8)

Comment: Algún comentario para -1 ??? al menos agregar la razón por la cual se supone mi respuesta es incorrecta :|